# Comparing data in two files in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two files,

File A:

```
Folder name A
   cp A
   cp B
Folder name B
   cp D
   cp F
```

File B:

```
Folder name C
    cp A
    cp B
Folder name A
    cp A
    cp B
    cp C
Folder name B
    cp D
    cp F
Folder name D
    cp A
    cp D
```

The output should be:

```
Folder name C:
     cp A
     cp B
Folder name D
     cp A
     cp D
Folder name A
     cp C
```

Basically, I want to check if there is a match in the folder name and then check for a match in the cp name for the same folder name. Then we need to delete the matches. Can anyone help me as I am new to perl.

I have code where it gives the folder names properly but deletes some of the cp names.

```
my %file2;
open my $file2, '<', 'fileA.txt' or die "Couldnt open fileA.txt";
while (my $line = <$file2>)
{
   ++$file2{$line};
 }
open my $file1, '<', 'fileB.txt' or die "Couldnt open fileB.txt";
while (my $line = <$file1>)
{
   print $fh $line unless $file2{$line};
 }
```

Comment: My script prints out the folder name properly, but once it comes across same cp name in two files, it deletes that cp name for all the folders.  In the above question, my script gives the output as Folder name C and Folder name D. But I want the output to be as explained in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Hunter McMillen for the edit.

Comment: Please show us what you have already done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the comparison logic is. In outputting `Folder C` I guess I see that it matches `Folder A` in fileA, but I don't understand why `Folder D` would be output; it doesn't match anything in fileA. If you're doing a diff, `Folder A` doesn't match between the two files. If you control the file format, have you considered using an existing format such as YAML, JSON or XML? That would make parsing it into a data structure much simpler.

Comment: It should output the difference between the two files

Comment: @Tej You're going to have to be more specific. Do you mean line by line? Run `diff fileA.txt fileB.txt`. Do you mean per folder? Then your expected output should include `Folder name A` because they contain different cp's. Do you just mean which folders are in one that aren't in the other, regardless of their content? That matches your expected output, but it doesn't match your description.

Comment: @Schwern We need to compare Folder name A of FileA.txt with Folder name A of FileB.txt, if the cp name matches in both the files for folder name A, then that particular folder has to be completely erased. If a cp name differs for a particular folder, then it should print the folder name and the differed cp name.

Comment: @Tej Your expected output does not match that description, it does not include `Folder name A`. Could you please update the post?

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for correcting me. Could you please help me in writing the code.

Comment: @Tej Now that I understand the problem, yes. :)

Comment: @Schwern Thank you. In the code which I have written it gets all the differed folder names, but it doesnt get the differed cp names properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems: parsing your data format, and doing the comparison.  You can't just compare the files line by line, your file has a structure and you need to parse it into a Perl data structure.

```
sub parse_file {
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $file;

    my $in_folder;
    my %folders = ();

    while(<$fh>) {
        # Entering a folder
        if( /^Folder name (.*)\s*$/ ) {
            $in_folder = $1;
        }
        # We're in a folder
        elsif( $in_folder ) {
            # Add a line to the folder actions
            if( /^\s+(.*)\s*$/ ) {
                push @{$folders{$in_folder}}, $1;
            }
            # We exited the folder but didn't enter another one
            elsif( /^\S/ ) {
                $in_folder = '';
            }
        }
    }

    return \%folders;
}
```

This is a lot of extra code to write and debug. If your files were stored in something like YAML, JSON or XML you could use a library to do it.

I've deliberately opted to strip out the formatting and just store the folder names. This makes the data easier to work with and shields the rest of the code from formatting changes.

Now each file is a hash of folder names which contain a list of commands.

```
      {
        'A' => [
                 'cp A',
                 'cp B'
               ],
        'B' => [
                 'cp D',
                 'cp F'
               ]
      }
```

Now we need to compare them.  The algorithm is like this:

1. If a folder is in only one file, pick it.
2. If a folder is on both files, show the differences (if any).

Fortunately, we have [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array%3a%3aUtils) to do all the necessary intersection and diffs for us. Use `array_diff` to find which folders are only in one file, and `intersection` to find those which are in both. Then use `array_diff` again to find the differences.

```
sub compare_folders {
    my($set1, $set2) = @_;

    my @set1_names = keys %$set1;
    my @set2_names = keys %$set2;

    my %diffs;

    # It's in one but not the other.
    for my $name (array_diff @set1_names, @set2_names) {
        $diffs{$name} = $set1->{$name} || $set2->{$name};
    }

    # It's in both.
    for my $name (intersect @set1_names, @set2_names) {
        # They're different
        if( my @diff = array_diff(@{$set1->{$name}}, @{$set2->{$name}}) ) {
            $diffs{$name} = \@diff;
        }
    }

    return \%diffs;
}
```

Finally we need to display the results. As I've opted to make the data generic and strip out the formatting, we need to put it back.

```
sub display_folder {
    my($name, $values) = @_;

    my $display = "Folder name $name\n";

    for my $value (@$values) {
        $display .= "    $value\n"
    }

    return $display;
}
```

And stick it all together.

```
my @folders = map { parse_file($_) } @ARGV;

my $diff = compare_folders(@folders);

for my $name (keys %$diff) {
    my $values = $diff->{$name};
    print display_folder($name, $values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Schwern. But how to send the two files? Like I need to read the data from fileA.txt and fileB.txt. After parsing both the files, then I need to compare them. From the code my folders = map { parse_file($_)} ARGV does the parsing. How do we send the two files?

Comment: Also can I use  manual comparison instead of using Array::Utils

Comment: You don't "send" files to Unix scripts. You pass the filenames as arguments and, in Perl, you read the arguments from `@ARGV`; then you pass them to a subroutine that reads the contents. That happens in the last block of code.

Comment: @reinierpost Thank you I had figured out that, but when I try to use Array::Utils it says not installed, is there any other way for comparisons

Comment: @Tej You could do the comparison manually, but you'd have to write your own array comparison routines, like you had to write your own parser, and your program gets bigger, and buggier and harder to maintain. Much easier to install the modules. Use [cpanm](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) for that.

Comment: @Schwern it is not allowing me to install as it is connected to university server and this code will be used my many others in the same server. Therefore can you help me with own comparison. Or give me some ideas on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Schwern I did some comparison and it is working. Thank you

Comment: @Tej I strongly encourage you to figure out how to get modules installed. Perhaps ask it as a question. That investment will save you time and frustration not having to write redundant code.

Comment: The trick is to install the modules in your `$HOME` directory; Perl supports ways to do that (e.g. the `use local lib` directive comes in handy, Google for it), but I've always find it tricky to see the forest for the trees when trying to find that out. If you set it up correctly, other users will be able to run your scripts, too, even with your modules installed there.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you, will try to do that. I have one more question, in the code which you have written, we have to pass the two files from command line argument. But, I want to open the two files, read and get the results from the script itself. How should I do that instead of using the command line? Thanks

Comment: @Tej `@ARGV` contains the list of files. Replace it with your list of your files. Though I'd encourage you to let the program take its files from the command line rather than hard coding them, it will be more flexible that way. Perhaps make your list a default: `@Default_Files || @ARGV`.